# Handling same event in more than one states in Workflow Foundation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, workflow-foundation

I'm using StateMachine Workflow. There are scenarios where same event can be fired in more than one states in workflow.

I want to know if i can handle same event in more than one states?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can listen for the same event in multiple states within a state machine workflow, but only the active state will be triggered when you fire the event.